# How to slide pages under appbar flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, user-interface, flutter-layout

I've been trying so hard to build page view system for quotes app. I want the page to flow full screen from top to bottom and bottom to top scrollable/swipe able to navigate between different quotes each time
like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jjue2.jpg). The scroll will bring new page each time its not casual scroll. I haven't found any guide regarding this on internet so far.

I don't know about how to build it, nothing is popping in my mind for days now. I've tried pageview with gesture detector for swiping up and down, it doesn't works as desired and appbar is static too and the bottom containers as well I don't want this. What I want is the page/screen to flow under the appbar or even a button on top right corner and under 2 buttons on the bottom.

Comment: Hey,Try this https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageView-class.html

Comment: A Listview should work. Try with ListView and if it doesn't work show me the code.

Comment: @AmonChowdhury Nah Listview would have worked if he placed all the quotes on the same page Since he is using a single quote per page Pageview would be more suitable

Comment: Will list view slide from below the containers/cards if I made any? If so then how. Do i have to give some property to the containers/cards i will make or the listview.

Comment: @SaiPrashanth Yes i am listing single quote per page. Pageview is working fine but not as desired it scrolls the whole page, I want 2 containers/cards or bottom navbar static fixed and the pages should slide through them as can be seen in the video i've attached

Comment: I suggest you take a look at this, https://medium.com/flutter-community/a-deep-dive-into-pageview-in-flutter-with-custom-transitions-581d9ea6dded

Comment: @SaiPrashanth  Thanks for it. Its Page Transitions and i've already done it as per told but its not like the video, in the video there are buttons fixed at top and bottom and page slides under them. I want that because i've planned multiple apps and they all will use this concept

Comment: Okay, are you using Floating Action Buttons?

Comment: ListView will work, you have to custom physics. I know PageView will not achieve the results you are expecting.

Comment: I'm not using floating action buttons, I've made cards. 
@AmonChowdhury Do you have any idea of how can I achieve this

Comment: Suggested is to go with pageview and provide navigation buttons in custom appbar, that would be more preferred i think.

Answer (score 0):

Create a column of Containers where each Container's height and width equals the height and width of the screen. You can do that by using:

```
height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
```

Also, make sure to wrap your code with a SingleChildScrollView widget to scroll vertically.

Here's the code:

```
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text(widget.title),
  ),
  body: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Center(child: Text('Quote number one')),
                Center(
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.share), onPressed: () {}),
                      IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.favorite), onPressed: () {})
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Text('Quote number two'),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.share), onPressed: () {}),
                    IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.favorite), onPressed: () {})
                  ],
                )
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

You can use PageView to get this type of view

[Drive Video link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Lq2bLYsj1wcHJXxruGrciqYcxMsmSNn-/view?usp=sharing)

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  PageController pageController;
  PageView pageView;

  List<String> quotes = [
    '#Quote 1\n\n“I\'m selfish, impatient and a little insecure. I make mistakes, I am out of control and at times hard to handle. But if you can\'t handle me at my worst, then you sure as hell don\'t deserve me at my best.” ',
    '#Qoute 2\n\nSo many books, so little time.',
    '#Quote 3\n\n A room without books is like a body without a soul'
  ];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    pageController = PageController();
    final _quotes = List.generate(quotes.length, (index) => quoteWidget(index));
    pageView = PageView(
      children: _quotes,
      controller: pageController,
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
    );
  }

  Widget quoteWidget(int index) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            flex: 3,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              child: Center(
                child: Text(
                  quotes[index],
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                FloatingActionButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: Icon(Icons.share),
                ),
                const SizedBox(width: 20),
                FloatingActionButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: Icon(Icons.favorite_border),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(child: Container())
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    pageController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      appBar: AppBar(
        brightness: Brightness.dark,
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Stack(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          children: [
            pageView,
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 10),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  RaisedButton.icon(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.menu_book),
                    label: Text('General'),
                    onPressed: () {},
                  ),
                  const Spacer(),
                  Container(
                    width: 50,
                    height: 50,
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                    ),
                    child: Icon(Icons.color_lens),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    width: 50,
                    height: 50,
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                    ),
                    child: Icon(Icons.person),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```